# Invoking (-) two times on different Nat variables within the same expression requires explicit proof annotation

Tags: idris

Consider this definition:

```
h : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
h x y = case 1 `isLTE` x of
              (Yes prf)   => case 1 `isLTE` y of
                                (Yes prf') => (x - 1) * 2 + (y - 1)
                                (No contra) => ?sr_3
              (No contra) => ?h_2
```

As innocent as it looks, it would not type check.

```
   |
14 |                                 (Yes prf') => (x - 1) * 2 + (y - 1)
   |                                                               ^
...
When checking an application of function Prelude.Interfaces.-:
        Type mismatch between
                Nat (Type of y)
        and
                LTE 1 x (Expected type)
```

For some reason, it cannot locate the right `prf`. *(Or is there something else going on?)* For some reason again, this error, while appearing in the second summand, can be fixed by annotating the minus in the first. This compiles:

```
h : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
h x y = case 1 `isLTE` x of
              (Yes prf) => case 1 `isLTE` y of
                                (Yes prf') => ((-) {smaller = prf} x 1) * 2 + (y - 1)
                                (No contra) => ?sr_3
```

#### My questions:

- What is happening?
- How can I express this logic better?
- Can I supply implicit arguments to infix operators, such as `-`, without converting them to prefix form `(-)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is happening?

This seems to be a bug in the unification, I guess. It should be able to infer everything correctly, but for the system it's apparently not clear which type you want to use. `+`, `*` are both `Num a => a -> a -> a`, and `-` even has two definitions; one with `Nat` and the proof, the other also in the `Num` format. So whenever there seems to be strange type mismatches, just clarify the types. `` (x - 1) * 2 `plus` (y - 1) `` also works out.

> How can I express this logic better?

You can join up both `case` statements:

```
g x y = case (1 `isLTE` x, 1 `isLTE` y) of
    (Yes lte1x, Yes lte1y) => (x - 1) * 2 `plus` (y - 1)
    _ => ?h
```

Even better, if you only need to subtract one, just do it via pattern matching:

```
i (S x) (S y) = x * 2 + y
i x y = ?h
```

Also, `Nat` is not always good for computation; it is better fitted for structural info for the type system (like in `Vect Nat a`). If you plan to do something like `x - 321 * y + 100` and do not need the result in a type, just drop to `Integer` for performance reasons.

> Can I supply implicit arguments to infix operators, such as -, without converting them to prefix form (-)?

Nope!

Comment: Do you also see this supposed bug if you try the code?

Comment: Yep, doesn't typecheck for me.